# angularjs-translate-loader-static-files with HotTowel template

Tags: angularjs, hottowel, angular-translate

I am trying to use angular-translate with static file-loader. My application is based on HotTowel template and below is my modified config file. I have added references to **angular-translate-loader-static-files.js** and **angular-translate.js** correctly and have injected  **'pascalprecht.translate'** to the app. It even loads the json file in /Languages/si-LK.json file. I can see it in Dev tools in the browser network tab. However translation is not working. And i am not seeing any error in the Console. It just displays the key only. I have the key in the Json file.

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('si-LK');
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: '/Languages/',
            suffix: '.json'
        });

    }]);
```

In my HTML i have this

```
<span>{{'INTROTEXT' | translate}}</span>
```

However if I switch to below, it all works. Any suggestion much appreciated.

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('si-LK');
$translateProvider.translations('en-US', {
    INTROTEXT: 'intro in English'
 }).translations('de', {
    INTROTEXT: 'intro in German'
    }).translations('si-LK', {
    INTROTEXT: 'Intro in sinhala'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I used partial loaders instead of staticFilesLoader. However what I think you are missing to call `run()` after `config()`

```
/*app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('si-LK');
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/Languages/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

}])*/
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider
        .useLocalStorage()
        .determinePreferredLanguage(function () { return 'pt'; })
        .useLoader("$translatePartialLoader", { urlTemplate: "/i18n/{part}.{lang}.json" });

}])
.run(function ($rootScope, $translate) {
    $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
        $translate.refresh();
    });
});
```

I hope that helps..

Comment: @ThiagePXP, no luck :-(, i tried to add a debug point ton $translate.refresh(), but never hit there.

Comment: where does the $translatePartialLoader comes from? it is complaining that it cant find the provider

Comment: you need this file: angular-translate-loader-partial.js